# How can I resize ImageView to window with only Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, fxml, scenebuilder

Is it possible to resize a ImageView node (child of AnchorPane) to the window size by only using Scene Builder? The only way I found was binding width/height properties of the ImageView to the window width/height properties. 
This would work for my purpose but I would like to keep the design inside the fxml file and no little bits of code here and there to fix the layout.
I hope someonr can help me out

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: No, you cannot use expression binding in SceneBuilder. Furthermore you're doing this on the completely wrong level. A scene does not know about the window contains it and getting from `Node` to `Window` also requires going through 2 "property levels" scene and window, both which are often not set at the time when a controller is initialized. Furthermore you cannot even be sure the root of the fxml will cover the whole window size instead of being added as child to another node. However if you need to do this note that you can also extend the controller class.

Comment: In this case, I'd be inclined to use [background fill specifiers in CSS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) to specify image coverage rather than an ImageView.